# Counting how many times the click() function has been used

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how many times the click() function has been used and log that but I always get the error called "undefined" or "NaN"

```js
var sleep = 1000;
var run = setInterval(function() {
  var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
    if (span[i].textContent != "danger") {
      var jump = document.getElementsByClassName("jump")[0].click();
      console.log(jump++);
    } else {
      clearInterval(run);
    }
  }
}, sleep);
```

```html
<span>Danger</span>
<button type="button" class="jump">Click</button>
```

Comment: this `document.getElementsByClassName("jump")[0].click();`  returns nothing, therefore the variable `jump` is undefined, so your `console.log(jump++);` logging undefined because incrementing undefined is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a counter variable!
Also, you don't have to use `getElementsByTagName` every time the interval is called, unless your DOM elements keep changing.

```
var sleep = 1000;
var counter = 0;
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var jump = document.getElementsByClassName("jump")[0];

var run = setInterval(function(){        
    for (var i =0; i< spans.length; i++) {
        if (spans[i].textContent != "danger") {
            jump.click();
            counter++;
            console.log(counter);
       } else {
            clearInterval(run);
       }
    }
}, sleep);
```

Comment: I'd also recommend not to use getElementsByClassName since querySelector/querySelectorAll is standard and supported by more browsers too

Answer (score 2):

You need to define jump and not assign the button to it
Also I recommend to use querySelector(All) instead of getElementsByClass/TagName

```js
var sleep = 1000, jump=0, jumpBut = document.querySelector(".jump");
var run = setInterval(function() {
// move this var outside the loop if the spans never change in number
  var span = document.querySelectorAll("span"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
    if (span[i].textContent != "danger") {
      jumpBut.click();
      console.log(jump++);
    } else {
      clearInterval(run);
    }
  }
}, sleep);
```

```html
<span>Danger</span>
<button type="button" class="jump">Click</button>
```

But try this instead - add a click event listener to the button and have that add to the counter

```js
var sleep = 1000, jump=0, jumpBut=document.querySelector(".jump");
jumpBut.addEventListener("click",function() {
  jump++,
  console.log(jump)
})
var run = setInterval(function() {
  var span = document.querySelectorAll("span");
  for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
    if (span[i].textContent != "danger") {
      jumpBut.click();
    } else {
      clearInterval(run);
    }
  }
}, sleep);
```

```html
<span>Danger</span>
<button type="button" class="jump">Click</button>
```